# Can you use the UIPageViewController to navigate throughout multiple view controllers?

Tags: ios

How would I go about using the `UIPageViewController` to give the effect of the page turning between multiple view controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erica Sadun' new book looks good: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1760500&seqNum=12[1](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1760500&seqNum=12)

I suggest ordering it and then downloading the current source code from:

https://github.com/erica/iOS-5-Cookbook[2](https://github.com/erica/iOS-5-Cookbook)

Also watch the video of session 102 from the WWDC 2011